# Counting occurrences of a word

Tags: c++, loops, count, ifstream

I'm trying to find the occurrences of a given word from an input file, and I'm able to correctly count the occurrences of a letter/character, but when I attempt to find a word the program just returns the count as 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
ifstream input("input.txt");
input.open("input.txt");
string video = "video", ands = "and";
string str1((istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
    istreambuf_iterator<char>());
int videocount = 0, sentcount = 0, wordcount = 0, wordcountand = 0, wordcountand2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
{
    if (str1 == video) {
        ++videocount;
    }

    if (str1[i] == '.') {
        sentcount++;
    }
    if (str1[i] == ' ') {
        wordcount++;
    }
    if (str1 == ands) {
        wordcountand++;
    }
}
```

Edit : I just changed the way the file was read and everything worked again.

```
while (input >> filewords) {
      {wordcount++; }
      if (filewords == word1) {
          ++videocount;
      }
      if (filewords == word2) {
          wordcountand++;
      }
        for (int i = 0; i < filewords.length(); i++) {
            if (filewords[i] == '.') {
                sentcount++;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: "when I attempt to find a word" Where? There isn't any code that attempts to find a specific word in your question. If you think it's this line `if (str1 == ands)` then no, `str1` is the entire file rather than a single word.

Comment: `ifstream input("input.txt");` opens the file for reading. `input.open("input.txt");` does it again -- not recommended. Why are you not reading with `while (input >> str1) { // now classify }`? Or use `while (getline (input, str1)) ...` and then `std::stringstream ss (str1);`. You can count whitespace from `str1` and use `while (ss >> word)` to count whitespace separated words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the question has already been answered in the comment. You cannot compare a search string to the complete text file that is stored in your variable "str1". The result will of course always be false.

The equal operator `==` does not look for sub-strings. And this brings us already to the answer, the algorithm that we want to use. We will use `std::string.substr`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) for a description of the function. The function parameters are:

- start position
- length of sub-string

So, we need to find the start-position of a word and the end-position of a word. With that, we can count the length of a word which is "end-position" - "start-position".

But how to identify a word? A word usually consists of alpha-numerical characters. And if we iterate through the complete text, and we compare the previous checked character, with the current evaluated character, we can state the following:

- If the previous charachter was NOT alpha-numeric and the current is, then we found the begin of a word. We will then remember the index, the start position of that word.
- If the previous charachter was alpha-numeric and the current ist not, then we found the end of a word. We can then start the comparisons, because we know start end end positions.

And then, something like `word = str1.substr(startPosition, endPosition-startPosition);` would give us a single word. This we can compare with our search words, like for example:

```
if (word == video) ++videocount;
```

But we can go further. With a very simple standard method, we can store and count all words. For that we can use a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. We use the `std::map`s index operator. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). And especially read the sentence:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

So, it will either create a new entry, or, find an existing entry. In any case, a reference (to the either already existing or the newly created entry) will be returned. And that will be incremented. This can then end up in something like:

```
wordCounter[text.substr(startIndexOfWord, index - startIndexOfWord)]++
```

So, here, we first build a sub-string using the already described algorithm. This sub-string is then either found or added to the `std::map`. In any case, a reference will be returned, which we will increment.

At the end, we will simply output all words and counters.

In the following proposal I am using C++17 and the features of C++17 like the `if`-statment with initializer or structured bindings. So you need to enable C++17 for your compiler.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if that works
    if (std::ifstream ifs("input.txt"); ifs) {

        // Read the complete text file into a string variable
        std::string text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

        // Define the counters
        size_t sentenceCounter{};
        std::map<std::string, size_t> wordCounter{};
        size_t overallWordCounter{};

        // And temporary storage of characters from the complete text
        char currentCharacter{};    char lastCharacter{};

        // Here we stort the index of a word start
        size_t startIndexOfWord{};

        // Iterate over all characters from the source file
        for (size_t index{}; index < text.length(); ++index) {

            // Read the current character
            const char currentCharacter = text[index];

            // Each dot will be counted as an indicator for a sentence
            if ('.' == currentCharacter) ++sentenceCounter;

            // Now check, if we have found the start of a word. The we will just store the index
            if (std::isalnum(currentCharacter) and not std::isalnum(lastCharacter))
                startIndexOfWord = index;

            // Now, check, if we found the end of a word. Add to map and increment counter
            if (std::isalnum(lastCharacter) and not std::isalnum(currentCharacter)) 
                wordCounter[text.substr(startIndexOfWord, index - startIndexOfWord)]++;

            // The next lastCharacter is the currentCharacter of now
            lastCharacter = currentCharacter;
        }

        // Go through the complete map
        for (const auto& [word, count] : wordCounter) {
            // SHow words and counters
            std::cout << std::left << "Word: " << std::setw(30) << word << " Count: " << count << "\n";
            // Calculate overall sum of words
            overallWordCounter += count;
        }
        // Show final result
        std::cout << "\nWords overall: \t" << overallWordCounter << "\nSentences: \t" << sentenceCounter << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n***Error: Could not open input file.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are many many other possible solutions, especially with `std::regex`.

If you have any questions, I am happy to answer